# Django widget HTML id

Tags: html, django, widget

In widget's code I need to get access to **HTML** id of the rendered element. I know I can run regexp on the rendered string and **get the ID**, but I believe there must be an easy way.

Let's assume this is the widget I have:

```
class TextInputWithHint(TextInput):
    ...
    def render(self, name, value, attrs):

        res = super(TextInputWithHint, self).render(name, value, attrs = attrs)
        res += mark_safe(u'<script type="text/javascript">alert(%s)</script>' \
        % self.attrs['id'])
        return res
```

Except that `self.attrs['id']` does not work.

Is there an easy way to obtain ID in here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use case, you can find the `id` attribute in the `attrs` argument that is passed to `render()`. It is a good idea to check for its existence before trying to use it:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
  # ...
  if attrs and 'id' in attrs:
    # Use attrs['id']
```

Comment: Is there a way to find it in the Django template language instead of rendering in Python?

Comment: @dfrankow: you can use {{ field.auto_id }} in templates